# Bootstrap 5 make a link not look like a link in both light and dark mode

Tags: bootstrap-5

A normal link is blue and underlined.

I want it to look like normal text, without forcing a specific color. I want it to automatically change without javascript in Dark / Light mode in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to fix the color of the link is to use the text-body class.

The solution to get rid of the underline is to style it with `style="text-decoration: none;"`

Here's the full answer:

```
<a href="/" class="text-body" style="text-decoration: none;">My Title</a>
```

This automatically changes to dark on a light background, and dark on a light background with bootstrap 5 light / dark mode.